# What library are HtmlUnitDriver & WebDriver part of?

Tags: scala, scalatest

Using below code (taken from http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_selenium)

```
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers
import org.scalatest.selenium.WebBrowser
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

class BlogSpec extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers with WebBrowser {

  implicit val webDriver: WebDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver

  "The blog app home page" should "have the correct title" in {
    go to (host + "index.html")
    title should be ("Awesome Blog")
  }
}
```

I receive the errors

```
 Multiple markers at this line
    - not found: type HtmlUnitDriver
    - not found: type WebDriver
```

Are the HtmlUnitDriver & WebDriver libraries not part of the scalatest installation, where can I import them from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed the Selenium dependency (http://seleniumhq.org/download/maven.html) :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.24.1</version>
    </dependency>
```